# Delay in storing the content of an event in array by one click in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React. I am working on a piece of code. I am trying to make a ToDoList kind of thing. So i have created 3 different component , one for taking input and one for displaying the entered code along with App.jsx.
Here are the code for each.

App.jsx

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import Header from "./Header";
    import Footer from "./Footer";
    import Note from "./Note";
    import CreateArea from "./CreateArea";

    function App() {
      const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
      function getData(note) {
        // setArr(previous => [...previous, { title: newTitle, content: newContent }]);
        setArr(previous => {return [...previous, note];});
        console.log(arr);
      }
      return (
        <div>
          <Header />
          <CreateArea reply={getData} />
          {arr.map((arry, index) => (
                <Note
                  key={index}
                  id={index}
                  title={arry.title}
                  content={arry.content} 
                />
              ))} 
          <Footer />
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

CreateArea.jsx

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";

    function CreateArea(props) {
      const [note, setNote] = useState({
        title: "",
        content: ""
      });

      function handleChange(event) {
        const { name, value } = event.target;

        setNote(prevNote => {
          return {
            ...prevNote,
            [name]: value
          };
        });
      }

      function submitNote(event) {
        // const newTitle = note.title;
        // const newContent = note.content;
        // props.reply(newTitle, newContent);
        props.reply(note);
        setNote({
          title: "",
          content: ""
        });
        event.preventDefault();
      }

      return (
        <div>
          <form>
            <input
              name="title"
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={note.title}
              placeholder="Title"
            />
            <textarea
              name="content"
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={note.content}
              placeholder="Take a note..."
              rows="3"
            />
            <button onClick={submitNote}>Add</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default CreateArea;
```

Note.jsx

```
    import React from "react";

    function Note(props) {
      return (
        <div className="note">
          <h1>{props.title}</h1>
          <p>{props.content}</p>
          <button>DELETE</button>
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default Note;
```

Now somehow i am getting the result right and the new post are being added as required but when I do a console.log for the array which stores inside getData() in App.jsx ,I observe there  is a delayy of one click before the array is being added.

[Sample problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w29z.png)

In the  images  attached.I have added new  post with random data but when i see the console log the array is still empty. When i click the Add button for the second time , only then [after second click on adding new post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jc4VC.png) is the data being shown. I can't seem  to figure out the reasoning behind it. Am I doing something wrong or missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `setArr()` from `useState()` is an asynchronous function. Hence, the `console.log(arr)` is called before the state is actually updated.

However, you can log `arr` in the `useEffect()` hook which is called on every state change, like this:

```
useEffect(() => {console.log(arr)})
```

You can find more information about this hook at https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html.

Comment: On adding the above statement . I am getting this  warning instead-State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument.

Comment: You don't need a second callback argument here; just use `useEffect()` hook. I already updated my answer several minutes ago. Try reloading the page to see my updated answer.

Comment: This works,thanks for explanation. Was forgetting about the asynchronous calls.

Answer (score 2):

This is delay is because `useState` mutation is asynchronous, you cannot get updated result in one tick.

try console.log result in `useEffect` hook like below:

```
function App() {
    const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
    function getData(note) {
        // setArr(previous => [...previous, { title: newTitle, content: newContent }]);
        setArr(previous => {
            return [...previous, note];
        });
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(arr);
    });
    return (
        <div>
            <CreateArea reply={getData} />
            {arr.map((arry, index) => (
                <Note
                    key={index}
                    id={index}
                    title={arry.title}
                    content={arry.content}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

more info: [hooks-reference.html#useeffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)